# My web app not showing on facebook native app

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

My app is showing on facebook desktop, m.facebook.com, but not on the native app?

I meant not showing on bookmark or favorite. When I search for it within the native app I can find it.

According to the documentation it should also appear on the native Facebook app bookmark?

Can anyone please advise what did I do wrong? I have set the mobile web setting already.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app has a native app, the it will show up in the Facebook app bookmark list.  If you app is a desktop or canvas app, it shows up on desktop.  If your app is a mobile site, then it shows up on m.facebook.com.  You need to specify the type of app or apps you support/have/exist in the developer dashboard for the app.

Comment: My app is a canvas app that supports mobile. But according to the documentation, the native app should also support the bookmark for mobilesite.

Comment: In the settings for your app you need to add a mobile URL.  The description for that setting is **Bookmark my web app on Facebook mobile.**